# How to compute the length/size/count of an Iterable?

Tags: typescript

I have a Props interface that uses an Iterable type on one of its fields, `data`:

```
interface Obj {
  key: string
  value: number
}

interface Props {
  data: Iterable<Obj>;
}
```

I would like to get the length/size/count of this `data` field in a generic way. One possibility is to add an additional field to Props that contains the precomputed length/size/count of `data`. Is there a more elegant way of computing the length of a generic iterable?

Comment: You can only consume the entire iterable and that will give you the count...but it also might exhaust it. Moreover, iterables might not even *have* a length - you can have an infinite one. For example a pRNG sequence.

Comment: Just as a quick demo: compare these: [count](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllAXDAklApgJwIYCMA26APGAK4C2uWAfDALwwDaAjADQwBM7AzALoB0AN2z5S6CAAoAlAG4AsAChFhWKFJhYDAAzyFAMxCYYE0JFhlyMGCD3woUmIqtW1GgNRvdi0xBCF++CAA5hIARK5IoewRsoqKBkYm4NAwFta2CA5Ozj5+6AHBEhaxSqW5-oEhoXpwYHAQABboACahskA) and [no count](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllAXDAklApgJwIYCMA26APGAK4C2uWAfDALwwDaAjADQwBM7AzALoB0AN2z5S6CAAoAlAG4AsAChFAegBUhWKFJhYDAAzyFAMxCYYE0JFhlyMGCCPwoUmIrt2tOgNRfDiyxAghPz4IADmEgBEnkiR7DGyqsqKiiZmFuDQMDb2jggubu4BQegh4RI2silKCsXBoRGRRnBgcBAAFugAJpGyQA)